# eventChannel - единственное событие - не срабатывает emmiter

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Всем привет.

Получаю данные из `firebase`. Событие стоит на `firebase.database().ref('.info/connected')`
Делаю для этого туннель (на картинки номер 1).

Проверяю юзера - в онлайн он или нет. Но если событие сразу возвращает TRUE (1)  - `const snapshot = yield take(chan)` (тонель) - НЕ отрабатывает.
а если обновить стараницу, и событие вернёт сначала false, а потом true, то тогда отрабатывает (2)

`const snapshot = yield take(chan);
 console.log('yura', 'info/connected - result eventChannel' , snapshot);`

Т.е. получается, когда я авторизируюсь, я сразу в онлайн, и событие возвращает СРАЗУ `TRUE`. И код не продолжается (консоль не отрабатывает. на картинке 1)

Вопрос: как добиться того, что бы он сразу отрабатывал, даже если первое (и единственное) событие true ?

Comment: Я так понимаю изначально признак, онлайн юзер или нет, который прописан в `initialState` у Вас `false` - и это верно. Если обновить страницу, то весть `store` у ридакса сбросится в начальные значения из `initialSate` прописанных в редьюсерах, а затем уже необходимых частях произойдет перезапись этих значений. Отсюда сначала `false`, а затем `true`, вроде бы всё логично. Хотя, я видимо не совсем понял суть вопроса.

Comment: не, это данные из firebase. То, что во второй раз, false, а потом true - это понятно. Проблема в другом: когда при первой загрузки firebase СРАЗУ возвращает true (на картинки номер 1) тоннель (или эммитер) не не срабатывает. не могу понять почему